# GIT push whines about untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed

Tags: git, macos, x11

I'm new to both git and OSX, coming from Ubuntu and svn.

When I do a "git push" from the OSX terminal shell, I get the following warning:

```
folklore$ git push origin master
Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
Counting objects: 7, done.
```

It seems to be working fine, its just a warning. But I dont' understand it. Why is there any X11 in play here?

I've checked my `.ssh/` keys and they are properly 600.

I guess I could just keep ignoring the warning, but I'd rather clean it up. And perhaps learn a bit.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This is an ssh issue, not a git issue. What you are seeing is not a git whine, it's a valid warning from your ssh client. You should ensure that your ssh config doesn't attempt X11 forwarding by default (git doesn't need it), or at least turn it off for the host you are connecting to.

In your `~/.ssh/config` try:

```
ForwardX11 no
```

either in the host specific section or globally.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I'm mangling my ssh options
This is from my .ssh/config

Host github
     HostName github.com 
     User      pfarrell
     IdentityFile       ~/.ssh/id_rsa
     ForwardX11 no


pfarrell@MBP:~/.ssh$ ssh git@github.com
Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.

Comment: You saved my life, otherwise I will use source tree

Answer (score 25):

If you want to get rid of this message for `github` (as deduced from your comments), your 
`~/.ssh/config` should contain:

```
Host *github.com
   ForwardX11 no
```

As the value after `Host` needs to be a **pattern** to match the hostname given to ssh. (You could e.g. also use `Host *github.*` ).

Of course other elements (`HostName`, `User`, etc.) can be added to this host as well.

Comment: Note that your github configuration should appear *above* your global options to take precedence over them.

Comment: @felix Yes, that follows from the fact that the first obtained value will be used for each parameter.